# Delay in android step counter

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am developing an android step counter that starts counting when i press a button and stops when i press the button again. The problem is that the counter always misses the first few steps i am using the step counter sensor introduced in android kitkat 4.4. I also tried the step detector sensor but had the same results.
I tried changing the delay when registering the sensor to fastest, game, normal, and I even tried to set the delay to 0 but nothing worked

Is there a way i can fix this?

this is a simple app that shows my problem
https://github.com/omaressameldin/simplestepcounter

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.oessa_000.simplestepcounter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;

    ToggleButton countToggle;
    TextView stepView;

    private int stepCount = 0;
    boolean toggle = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        stepView = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.stepView);
         countToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.countToggle);
        ;

        countToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle = !toggle ;
                if(toggle){
                startListening();
                }
                else{
                    stopListening();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void startListening() {

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    }

    protected void stopListening() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
    }



    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        switch(sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER:
                if (toggle){
                    stepCount++;
                    stepView.setText("Step Count: " + stepCount);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.oessa_000.simplestepcounter.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step Count: 0"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/stepView"

        />
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/countToggle"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textOff="Not Walking"
        android:textOn="Walking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stepView"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oessa_000.simplestepcounter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edited: Added code snippets

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i added a link that shows my problem thank you :)

Comment: do not link outside. The target site may be gone rendering your question unclear or cryptic to future readers. Please edit your question and include all information needed.

Comment: I added the code snippets @Marcin Orlowski

Comment: Step counting is not an exact science. This might be an intentional delay to minimize false positives. It may or may not get fixed if you are walking for a longer time through some correction factor of statistical approach, depends on how sophisticated the implementation is - however that is unlikely. Do the first few steps really matter if you walk for a thousand?

Comment: well they don't matter if i walk for a thousand but the project i am working on is that i wanna know the distance walked from a start of a room till the end, so every single step counts becasue you only walk for like 5-10 steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that using the predefined stepCounter sensor for small number of steps, like what i wanted, isn't the best option and implementing a counter using accelerometer would be a lot better; however it won't be recommended for building fitness apps or any app that require constant step counting for a long time because the delay in the stepcounting sensor is to neglect the false positives.

so this is my implementation of the stepcounter using accelerometer

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.oessa_000.testcompass;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{


    // Gravity for accelerometer data
    private float[] gravity = new float[3];
    // smoothed values
    private float[] smoothed = new float[3];
    // sensor manager
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    // sensor gravity
    private Sensor sensorGravity;
    private double bearing = 0;

    private TextView acc;
    private TextView stepView;
    private TextView thresholdView;
    private SeekBar seek;
    private ToggleButton countToggle;

    private int stepCount;
    private boolean toggle;
    private double prevY;
    private double threshold;
    private boolean ignore;
    private int countdown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        acc = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.accelerometer));
        thresholdView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.thresholdView));
        stepView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.stepView));
        countToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.countToggle);
        seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);

        seek.setProgress(0);
        seek.incrementProgressBy(1);
        seek.setMax(40);
        // keep screen light on (wake lock light)

        implementListeners();
    }

    protected float[] lowPassFilter( float[] input, float[] output ) {
        if ( output == null ) return input;
        for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
            output[i] = output[i] + 1.0f * (input[i] - output[i]);
        }
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorGravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        // listen to these sensors
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorGravity,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // remove listeners
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorGravity);
    }







    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // get accelerometer data
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            // we need to use a low pass filter to make data smoothed
            smoothed = lowPassFilter(event.values, gravity);
            gravity[0] = smoothed[0];
            gravity[1] = smoothed[1];
            gravity[2] = smoothed[2];
            acc.setText("x: "+gravity[0] + " y: " + gravity[1] + " z: " + gravity[2]+ "ignore: "+ ignore + "countdown: "+ countdown);
            if(ignore) {
                countdown--;
                ignore = (countdown < 0)? false : ignore;
            }
            else
                countdown = 22;
            if(toggle && (Math.abs(prevY - gravity[1]) > threshold) && !ignore){
                stepCount++;
                stepView.setText("Step Count: " + stepCount);
                ignore = true;
            }
            prevY = gravity[1];
        }
    }

    public void implementListeners(){
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                threshold = ((double)seek.getProgress()) * 0.02;
                thresholdView.setText("Threshold: "+ threshold);
            }
        });

        countToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle = !toggle ;
                if(toggle){
                    stepCount = 0;
                    countdown = 5;
                    ignore = true;
                    stepView.setText("Step Count: " + stepCount);
                }
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.oessa_000.testcompass.MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_below="@+id/degree"
        android:id="@+id/accelerometer"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step Count: 0"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/stepView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/accelerometer"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stepView"
        android:id="@+id/thresholdView"
        />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thresholdView"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/countToggle"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textOff="Not Walking"
        android:textOn="Walking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seek"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adjusting the threshold sets the sensitivity of the sensor :)

Reference: http://nebomusic.net/androidlessons/Pedometer_Project.pdf